# Dynamic Routes at Home Router

Tags: networking, routing

I am currently using a linux box as my home router (PPPoE to my ISP and NAT, etc).

Some websites are blocked in my country (don't say the name out loud), so I have another PPP in my router to a VPN server in another country, just to bring those sites back (google, youtube, facebook, etc)

Currently, I have two WiFi AP in this box, one is using local ISP as default route, and another is using PPP. Apparently I need to switch over two APs in this setting, just to compromise between high speed to local web service, and accessibility to those blocked sites.

It sucks.

I am wondering whether there exists some tools to dynamically manage routes to choose optimum path, based on ping round time.

An assumed work flow could be like this:
when I access a webpage at 123.58.180.8, it sends out two beacons to this IP, one through PPP, another through local ISP, and finds out that local one is much faster. Then it looks up this IP via whois or other reverse dns means, then discover an IP block of 123.58.0.0/16 where this specific IP resides in. Then, a route will be inserted to my routing table. There should be a heartbeat to maintain the routing table if a route is not hit for a long time.

Thanks in advance and please keep this discussion at a pure technical level, no politics.

Edit:
Currently, I am manually adding routes that I know but this task is very trivial. It would also be good if I could keep a piece of software running for couple of days to accumulate routing knowledge about what sites are blocked and speed comparison.

I am using an Alix board as router and running Debian in it, since I am running some other services in it as well.

Comment: It’s probably wiser to statically administer routes. After all, you probably know which services are blocked and, as such, when to use the VPN connection. Specifically, which router models are we talking about here?

Comment: @DanielB The Great Firewall is adaptive and intelligent, which sometimes allows traffic and sometimes doesn't. Also, some CDN servers are blocked from time to time as well. That's why I want to dynamically manage routes. Also, higher speed via PPP can be a side effect. I supplemented the post with some more details. thanks